# Set margin on bootstrap cols without affecting width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, responsive

I am trying to display a list of card width boostrap. I made my html like so :

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, margin seems to expand the cards' width. So it makes someting like that... (it should display 4 cols)

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekyyq.jpg)

If I remove margins, it makes something like...

[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erkcT.jpg)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. However it does not solve my problem :(

First solution :
I cannot do that easily because I get them from a database so I don't know how many elements will be returned and I do really want to make a new deck card every 4 cards.
The justify-content-center is not really elegant and it shifts the problem

Second solution :
It looks like my second screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/erkcT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You must use padding, don't margin if you don't want any cards size change.

change

```
        <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
```

with this

```
       <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 p-2">
```

```html
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 p-2">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin can not increase the width of card like that. However, it will definitely increase container's width.

**APPROACH 1:** Check the code below. It will assign equal widths to the cards.

***NOTE :*** It is working like row-column feature of bootstrap. So you have to add n number of  `card`  elements in a  `card-deck`  for n number of columns.

```html
<div class="card-deck mx-2 mt-2">
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-deck mx-2">
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**APPROACH 2:** In case you don't want to change card's width :

```html
<div class="card-deck m-2 mb-0 justify-content-center">
  <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-widget col-sm-2 m-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Bootstrap 5)

I was able to solve the problem by wrapping the card in a column first (which is what the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#using-grid-markup) recommends). This appears to apply an mx-2 margin as a default, though I can't actually find out why this is the case. In any case it allowed me to get a margin between cards without breaking the grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 my-2">
      <div class="card">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 my-2">
      <div class="card">
      </div>
    </div>
    ...etc
  </div>
</div>
```